# How to show a Webview in a Mac Dashboard Widget?

Tags: html, macos, dashcode, mac-dashboard-widget

I am making a simple Mac Dashboard widget which would show a webpage in a webview, from a user selectable URL.

To be honest, I assumed there would simply be a 'webview' type part in the Library which I could just drop on. I've tried fiddling with the canvas part and Googling, but to no avail.

Any ideas of how to simply show `http://www.example.com/page.html` in a widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody comes here from a search or something, I ended up solving my problem by just viewing the widget's HTML and adding an `<iframe>` to it. Don't know why I didn't think of that before, but it all works fine.